# MVC 4 Redirect error page when Authorization page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have implemented CustomRoleProvider which seems to be working fine. However when the Authorization fails, I am seeing a popup window which says, "Windows Security" asking to enter userid and password. What I would like to do is when the Authorization fails, Redirect the user to the error page. Here's the snippet of the code.

When the User role is not Admin, it is showing a popup window.

```
[CustomAuthorize]
[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
public ActionResult ManageTickets(ticketViewModel viewModel)
{
return View;
}
```

I have also tried to customrize HandleUnauthorizedRequest method, but it is not working. In debug mode, this code doesn't even get executed, I just get the popup window.

```
 public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
            }
            else
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new
                System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "ErrorController", area = "Core", action = "Error" }));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Using, Windows authentication mode -

```
<authentication mode="Windows">
```

Appriciate any advice, thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this is because Windows Auth sends HTTP 401 Challenge so if it's not authenticated it will pop up the login dialog you're seeing. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005501/a-better-way-to-get-a-windows-username-using-forms-authentication and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972958.aspx They may apply, I think though that changing to Forms authentication and auto logging in a Windows user might be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Probably windows auth returns status code 401. 401 means:

> If the request already included Authorization credentials, then the 401 response indicates that authorization has been refused for
>   those credentials.

to be sure add this code to web.config and see what happen:

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="Your Default Url" mode="RemoteOnly">
  <error statusCode="401" redirect="~/core/error/error" />
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/core/error/error" />
</customErrors>
```

Comment: I have 401 status code on the web.config but still same popup error message comes.

Comment: code was edited, try it. replace this `~/core/error/error` with your error url if it's not correct.

Comment: I replaced the code with my error page but still it shows the popup window. I think I may have to change the authentication to Forms and then somehow do WIndows Authentication. Not sure how to do that.