# Query for Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

I've a web application that use Forms Authentication, now I would like(for some reason) to query the server to check if username exist in the Windows users(like windows authentication)

It this possibile?

I hope I explained

Sorry for my poor english

Comment: What have you tried, where is the code? If you can login one user why can't you check the credentials of another? Why have you tagged this both form- and windows authentication, which is it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is impossible to retrieve the Username of a Windows user as long as you are using Forms Authentication. 
If you really have to use Forms Authentication there might be a workaround. 
Take a 
[look at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005501/a-better-way-to-get-a-windows-username-using-forms-authentication).

The method described here is creating a seperate project which uses Windows Authentication to get the username and afterwards redirecting to your main project and passing the username as a parameter. 
I hope this is helpfull.